# How can i implement localization functionality in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios8

I'm currently developing an ios application with default language as english. I want to localize it to Hungarian Language. So how can i translate the complete app to Hungarian? How can i implement localization functionality in ios?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if a quick internet search didn't turn up many articles on IOS localisation. Oh look! : https://www.google.com.au/webhp?#q=ios+localization

Comment: Actually i  refered many articles, but i didn't came up with best solution. That's why i posted a question like this..

Comment: so where exactly are you stuck???

Comment: which one is better - Tethras, One Sky or iCanlocalize?

Comment: better? better using what metric?

Comment: Do you have experience in this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79291/discussion-between-anamika-and-mitch-wheat).

Comment: @MitchWheat please try to help her if you have good knowledge in IOS

Comment: @Anamika see this link you will get step by step process for localised you app. i also implemented a app through this link ,https://www.clairereynaud.net/blog/getting-your-iphone-app-ready-for-localization/

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial taken from Ray Wenderlich site:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014